# applicationDidBecomeActive not firing in Cordova app

Tags: objective-c, cordova, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to add the Facebook SDK to my Cordova app to track installs. In [Facebook App Ads Setup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk) they require that you add

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

I added that snippet of code to my AppDelegate.m and included an NSLog and it doesn't ever get called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u try including the NSLog in other app delegate methods like for ex: applicationDidFinishLaunching and see if any of them are called ?

Comment: Yes I added a log to applicationDidFinishLaunching and that got called and if I move the Facebook snippet that gets called too. I'm just concerned if diverging from the Facebook instructions is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this problem or at least a reason why some system responders may not fire up in `Cordova` projects:

If you're using a plugin that extends `AppDelegate` to access lifecycle responders [in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) you may not be aware, that some other component also extends `AppDelegate` and is already using this responder, this makes responder inaccessible in your implementation.

In my case: 
I was making a delegate that would blur the screen to hide sensitive personal data before making snapshot and sent application to background, I needed to add some code to

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{}
```

I was not getting any response from `DidBecomeActive` though, even if I was simply trying to `NSLog` something. I searched project for `DidBecomeActive` key and it appeared that [FirebasePlugin](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2BFirebasePlugin.m) was already using this method for some other stuff (this plugin was added to project by another person so I was not aware of how it works).
What I did is simply moved my code to Firebase plugin and implemented missing responders, because I only had about 10 lines all together.

Comment: I have exacly your same issue with the FirebasePlugin, but I don't want to change the plugin code, so I don't really know how to solve the issue. Is there a way to use a listener instead of overriding the method?

Comment: @santi The question you're looking answer for is how to attach to application state responder simultaneously from multiple classes. From my experience when I was trying to solve this problem there wasn't any, or at least I haven't found one.

Answer (score 0):

**applicationDidBecomeActive** method is called when app transition from Background to Foreground. When user receives a call,sms etc or presses the home Button the app goes to background (to save battery etc); After the end of call or multitasking the app is activated again. Then the **applicationDidBecomeActive** method is called. It should be used mostly to refresh tableviews and such.

Here is the Apple Documentation for the same method.

> This method is called to let your app know that it moved from the
>   inactive to active state. This can occur because your app was launched
>   by the user or the system. Apps can also return to the active state if
>   the user chooses to ignore an interruption (such as an incoming phone
>   call or SMS message) that sent the app temporarily to the inactive
>   state.
>
> You should use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or
>   not yet started) while the app was inactive. For example, you could
>   use it to restart timers or throttle up OpenGL ES frame rates. If your
>   app was previously in the background, you could also use it to refresh
>   your app’s user interface.

What is happening is perfectly Normal and Facebook ads should be working correctly.

Please refer the following docs to get a deeper understanding of iOS App Life Cycle and App Delegate Methods.

[The App Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

[UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what applicationDidBecomeActive is supposed to do. In the [Facebook FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/resources/faqs#test-app) it states that once the app is opened with the applicationDidBecomeActive code there should be a record of the app being installed. When I move that code to applicationDidFinishLaunching I get a install record, but I'm not sure if that is an encouraged deviation from the facebook docs.

Comment: I haven't started any campaigns yet because I want to pay per download and the code to track whether the app was downloaded isnt functioning appropriately.

Comment: Well you can test your ads. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing). I hope you find it useful.